# Getting Form fields that were added using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using the code below to add in a new product line when the user clicks on "Add new item", but once I submit the form the added rows are nowhere to be found.

I have tried dumping the form and the only form fields that appear are the ones that are on the page once it has loaded so I cannot get the data for the rest of the rows.

I have tried moving the form tags around without any luck

Below is the page with the script that I use to add in new rows:

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm">
<cfparam name="form.step" default="1">
<cfparam name="form.submit" default="">

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = 1;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
currentItem++;
$('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Itemname'+currentItem+'" id="Itemname'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" id="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="Quantity'+currentItem+'" id="Quantity'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input type="text" name="Code'+currentItem+'" id="Code'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input type="text" name="Price'+currentItem+'" id="Price'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td></tr>';
  $('#data').append(strToAdd);

 });
 });

 //]]>
 </script>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="CopyWhite" align="left" background="images/tab_bg.gif" colspan="2">Add a new invoice</td>
</tr>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif form.step eq 1>
        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <cfquery name="get_vendors" datasource="#application.db#">
                SELECT * FROM tblpassVendor
                WHERE vendoractive = 1
                AND companyid = #session.companyid#
            </cfquery>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Invoice Using:</td>
                <td>
                    <Select name="INVBY">
                        <cfloop query="get_vendors">
                            <option value="#vendorid#">#vendorname#</option>
                        </cfloop>
                    </Select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
                <input type="Reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" class="submitbutton">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 2>
        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="vendor" value="#FORM.INVBY#" />
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Order Details:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Reference Number:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="REFNUM" required="yes" message="Please enter a User Name" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Billing Details:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NAME" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Surname:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="LNAME" required="yes" message="Please enter a Surname" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Tel:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="TEL" required="yes" message="Please enter a Tel" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" required="yes" message="Please enter a Email" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Address line 1:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ADDR1" required="yes" message="Please enter Address line 1" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Address line 2:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ADDR2" required="yes" message="Please enter Address line 2" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">City/Town:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="CITY" required="yes" message="Please enter a City/Town" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Province/Region:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="REGION" required="yes" message="Please enter a Province/Region" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Country:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="COUNTRY" required="yes" message="Please enter a Country" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">ZIP/Postal Code:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ZIP" required="yes" message="Please enter a ZIP/Postal Code" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3" />
                <input type="Reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" class="submitbutton">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 3>
        <!---WRITE DATA TO TBLINV--->
        <cfquery name="write_inv" datasource="#application.db#" result="test">
            INSERT INTO tblpassInv
            (INVVENDORID,INVREF,INVNAME,INVLNAME,INVTEL,INVEMAIL,INVADDR1,INVADDR2,INVCITY,INVREGION,INVCOUNTRY,INVZIP,INVCOMPANY,INVCREATEDBY,INVDATECREATED,INVACTIVE,INVSEND)
            VALUES
            (#form.vendor#,'#form.REFNUM#','#form.NAME#','#form.LNAME#','#form.TEL#','#form.EMAIL#','#form.ADDR1#','#form.ADDR2#','#form.CITY#','#form.REGION#','#form.COUNTRY#','#form.ZIP#',#session.companyid#,#session.adminid#,#createodbcdatetime(now())#,1,0)
        </cfquery>
        <cfset NewPrimaryKey = test.GENERATED_KEY>
        <!---<cfinclude template="inv_amend_prods_new.cfm">--->
        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Products/Line Items:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <table border="0" id="data" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Itemname1" id="Itemname1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ItemDesc1" id="ItemDesc1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Quantity1" id="Quantity1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Code1" id="Code1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Price1" id="Price1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#NewPrimaryKey#" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 4>
        <cfdump var="#form#">
        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Display all details for invoice:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="5" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#form.invid#" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 5>
        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Bcc:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="bcc" required="yes" message="Please enter a bcc" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="6" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#form.invid#" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form.step eq 6>
        <cfset invid = form.invid>
        <cfinclude template="inv_mail.cfm">
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
<cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

Page source (for header and footer):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/loginstyle.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mailstyle.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.miniColors.css" />
<style type="text/css">
@import "calendar/jquery.datepick.css";
/* Or use these for a ThemeRoller theme instead
@import "themes16/southstreet/ui.all.css";
@import "css/ui-southstreet.datepick.css";
*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.miniColors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.miniColors2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>



<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
</head>



<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=600,height=600,left = 340,top = 180');");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//  $.datepick.setDefaults({useThemeRoller: true});
    $('#date1').datepick();
    $('#date2').datepick();
    $('#date3').datepick();
    $('#date4').datepick();
    $('#date0').datepick();
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}


function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>


<table align="center" width="1000px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px;"><img src="images/logo.png" width="400"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="2">
        <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden">
        <a href="index.cfm?ACTION=LOGOUT">Log Out</a>
        </div>
    </td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="250" style="padding-left:10px; border-right:1px solid #cccccc" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <table width="100%" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="navsub" align="left">Your Account</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" class="Header3">Quick Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" class="Copy" id="LogoutBlue">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" align="middle"><br>
                <font class="Copy">Username:</font> demo<br>
                <font class="Copy">Name:</font> Demo Login<br>
                <font class="Copy">Current Language:</font> English <img src="../images/flags/A22921BD-0055-9C1B-F9C07345BEF072E7.png" align="absmiddle" /><br>
                <font class="Copy">Mode:</font> Live Mode<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td class="nav-button">

                    <A href="company_amend2.cfm">Manage Company</A>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="nav-button">
                    <A href="vendor_add.cfm">Setup New Vendor</A>
                    <A href="vendor_amend.cfm">Manage Vendors</A>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="nav-button">
                    <A href="inv_new.cfm">Setup New Invoice</A>
                    <A href="inv_amend.cfm">Manage Invoices</A>
                    <A href="inv_delete.cfm">Delete Invoices</A>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="nav-button">
                    <A href="user_add.cfm">Setup New User</A>
                    <A href="user_amend.cfm">Manage Users</A>
                    <A href="user_delete.cfm">Delete Users</A>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr> 
                <Td>&nbsp;</Td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="800px" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">



<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = 1;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
currentItem++;
$('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Itemname'+currentItem+'" id="Itemname'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" id="ItemDesc'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="Quantity'+currentItem+'" id="Quantity'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input type="text" name="Code'+currentItem+'" id="Code'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input type="text" name="Price'+currentItem+'" id="Price'+currentItem+'" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td></tr>';
  $('#data').append(strToAdd);

 });
 });

 //]]>
 </script>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="CopyWhite" align="left" background="images/tab_bg.gif" colspan="2">Add a new invoice</td>
</tr>



        <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Products/Line Items:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <table border="0" id="data" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Itemname1" id="Itemname1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ItemDesc1" id="ItemDesc1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Quantity1" id="Quantity1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Code1" id="Code1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Price1" id="Price1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="33" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>


    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" valign="top"><img src="images/footer.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have noticed that the value for items which is hidden is updating correctly but I cant see any of the additional rows

I have also noticed that when I view page source there is only one row item so I am not sure if the issue is with my script

Please see my cfdump below (I have added 4 row items):

[image]

Inspect Request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Itemname1"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ItemDesc1"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Quantity1"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Code1"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Price1"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Submit"

Submit
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items"

2
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEDCIVZAMPMo4mt4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="step"

4
```

When I view source code on firefox I get the following (I have added 4 line items):

```
<form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Products/Line Items:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <table id="data" class="Border" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Itemname1" id="Itemname1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="ItemDesc1" id="ItemDesc1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Quantity1" id="Quantity1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td>
                <td><input name="Code1" id="Code1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td>
                <td><input name="Price1" id="Price1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input name="Itemname2" id="Itemname2" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input name="ItemDesc2" id="ItemDesc2" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input name="Quantity2" id="Quantity2" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input name="Code2" id="Code2" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input name="Price2" id="Price2" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input name="Itemname3" id="Itemname3" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input name="ItemDesc3" id="ItemDesc3" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input name="Quantity3" id="Quantity3" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input name="Code3" id="Code3" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input name="Price3" id="Price3" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td><td><input name="Itemname4" id="Itemname4" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td><td><input name="ItemDesc4" id="ItemDesc4" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td><td><input name="Quantity4" id="Quantity4" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td><td><input name="Code4" id="Code4" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr><tr><td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td><td><input name="Price4" id="Price4" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton" type="Submit">
                <input id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" type="button">
                <input id="items" name="items" value="4" type="hidden">
                <input name="step" value="4" type="hidden">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

There seems to be no form closing tag

Please advise on how I can solve this issue

Thank you in advance

Comment: It works for me. Check out this jsFiddle and let me know if this is what you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/j9m68yea/

Comment: Hi @Narxx! The rows are adding perfectly, the issue I have is that once I submit the form the rows variables are not there

Comment: Can you include the output of your `<cfdump>` in your question, pls.

Comment: Hi @AdamCameron I have included the dump into my question, please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: And if you inspect the request when you submit the form, are the new form fields actually being sent to the web server? They do for me (using that jsfiddle @Narxx posted.

Comment: Hi @AdamCameron I am not sure how to do that, could you please advise?

Comment: @Dave - load up chrome developer tools, and look at the network tab. load the Network tab, and then check the 'preserve log' checkbox. Now reload/resubmit the form; find the POST request and look at the data it's sending - are the form fields there? Could be something as simple as the form fields not being attached within the <form> tag due to an early closing tag etc.

Comment: @AdamCameron I have updated my question, I hope that was what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks @Neokoenig I have updated my question, please let me know if there is anything else

Comment: Ok, so your additional form fields aren't being submitted. Usually, the reason for this is a bad bit of markup which means the form fields are actually getting rendered outside the form. NB: Chrome inspect element often tries to 'fix' the HTML for you, so if you want to be absolutely sure of the actual generated markup, Firefox web developer toolbar has a 'View Generated Source' which will render the actual source code as is 'currently' on the screen. The other thing to try is to capture all the form fields via jQuery and submit that way.

Comment: Thanks @Neokoenig I have updated my question again with the source code using firefox

Comment: So where in the source code are the additional form fields? If you can see them on page, they *are* in there - but as I said, you need to be looking at the *Generated* source code which would include any additional markup added by Javascript after the initial page load.

Comment: Hi @Neokoenig it seems like there is not form closing tag, but I do have one in my code. Could it be that the JavaScript is removing my closing form tag?

Comment: It's probably that you've got the <form> tag within a nested table - i.e, when you add a <tr>, the dom is revaluated and the form closes as the markup is incorrect, as I think you can't just chuck a form start tag in like that. Try moving the <form> tags OUTSIDE of any table markup. As you've not posted the whole page, it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi @Neokoenig I have tried by moving the form tags but it did not seem to work, I have also updated my question and added in all of my code

Comment: OK, so this is not a ColdFusion question, as the form fields in question are never being submitted, this is why they're never getting to the CF server. I don't want to be unhelpful by offering that as an "answer", but you need to revise your question to reflect it's a JS / DOM issue, not a CF one. So as to attract the right ppl to answer it.

Comment: Agreed with Adam. On a coldFusion note, please please please go and read up on cfqueryparam, like, now.

Comment: This most likely is because of what @Neokoenig said. Your `<form>` tags are nested all wrong. If you have changed this like you mentioned, can you update your question to reflect this code. `<form>` can only go around a `<table>` or with in the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what I did to fix this issue is

page.cfm:

```
<cfif form.step eq 3>
    <form method="post" action="inv_new.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
</cfif>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="Border" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="CopyWhite" align="left" background="images/tab_bg.gif" colspan="2">Add a new invoice</td>
</tr>

<cfoutput>

<cfif form.step eq 3>
        <!---WRITE DATA TO TBLINV--->
        <cfquery name="write_inv" datasource="#application.db#" result="test">
            INSERT INTO tblpassInv
            (INVVENDORID,INVREF,INVNAME,INVLNAME,INVTEL,INVEMAIL,INVADDR1,INVADDR2,INVCITY,INVREGION,INVCOUNTRY,INVZIP,INVCOMPANY,INVCREATEDBY,INVDATECREATED,INVACTIVE,INVSEND)
            VALUES
            (#form.vendor#,'#form.REFNUM#','#form.NAME#','#form.LNAME#','#form.TEL#','#form.EMAIL#','#form.ADDR1#','#form.ADDR2#','#form.CITY#','#form.REGION#','#form.COUNTRY#','#form.ZIP#',#session.companyid#,#session.adminid#,#createodbcdatetime(now())#,1,0)
        </cfquery>
        <cfset NewPrimaryKey = test.GENERATED_KEY>
        <!---<cfinclude template="inv_amend_prods_new.cfm">--->
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table  id="data">
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Products/Line Items:</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Itemname1" id="Itemname1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Name" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Item Description:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ItemDesc1" id="ItemDesc1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Description" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Quantity1" id="Quantity1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Quantity" class="TextBlock">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Product Code:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Code1" id="Code1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Code" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Copy" valign="top">Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Price1" id="Price1" required="yes" message="Please enter a Price" class="TextBlock"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
                <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="invid" value="#NewPrimaryKey#" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </cfif>
```

footer.cfm

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" valign="top"><img src="images/footer.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<cfif form.step eq 3>
    </form> 
</cfif>
</body>
</html>
```